# MonoTouch.Dialog support for Pull to Refresh in iOS 7

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, ios7, pull-to-refresh

I'm using the native MonoTouch.Dialog support for Pull to Refresh feature on iOS, however since in iOS 7 view controllers can be shown in fullscreen mode (below the navigation bar and status bar) the Pull to Refresh feature stopped working properly.

I tried to play with `TableView.ContentOffset` and `TableView.ContentInset` properties in my `MonoTouch.Dialog.DialogViewController` subclass but I could not find any point of customization.  `MonoTouch.Dialog.DialogViewController` uses a lot of private constants / fields / classes, which makes difficult to extend it.

Also the https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog looks outdated.

Is anyone successfully using Pull to Refresh feature in iOS 7 with MonotTouch.Dialog?

Comment: I have created a [pull request](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/pull/191) for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I suddenly realized that my app deployment target is iOS >= 6.x (I have recently dropped support for iOS 5) so I can use the `UIKit`s native `UIRefreshControl` instead, which scales will with both iOS 6 and iOS 7 ;).

Comment: Forgot mentioning http://conceptdev.blogspot.com.br/2012/09/ios-6-uirefreshcontrol-with-monotouch.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and had a different solution. I was doing the following

```
public MyController()
    : base(null)
{
    RefreshRequested += MyController_RefreshRequested;
    Root = new RootElement(null);
}
```

I was immediately calling ReloadComplete, this is bad dont do this

```
void MyController_RefreshRequested(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
InvokeOnMainThread(
delegate
     {
     ReloadComplete();
     }
}
```

You need to wait just a little before refreshing...

```
void MyController_RefreshRequested(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     InvokeOnMainThread(
     delegate
     {
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
          ReloadComplete();
     }
}
```

btw, the original problem looks like it was fixed on github by bhomles: https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/issues/190